# snowflake substring regrex

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

im using sql in snowflake and i have a column full of ID strings, some are all numbers, some contain letters.
I want to do a case when i select the product ids with letters in the string, and then take the portion of the string before the letters. eg

'234HJ7' --> '234'

'3333J1' ---> '3333'
etc.

Ive tried the following but cant get the output i need:

`SUBSTRING(string_id, 1, POSITION('[a-zA-Z'] IN string_id)-1 )`

`regexp_substr(string_id, '[a-zA-Z]', 1,  1)`

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to do it using [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr) :

```
SELECT *, regexp_substr(string1, '\\d+') as "RESULT"
FROM mytable;
```